# Using projection with a interface in `@Query` annotation with a native query gives "Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found"

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a table with a clob in an oracle 19 database which I try to fetch with a native query using a `@Query` annotation with a projection from a Spring boot 2.7.4 application. I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot project jdk.proxy2.$Proxy281 implementing java.sql.Clob,org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.WrappedClob,java.io.Serializable to java.lang.String; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found
```

The query from my repository class:

```
@Query(
       value = """
               select submission_id as "submissionId", text as "textAnswer"
               from answer
               where answer_id = :answerId
               """,
       nativeQuery = true)
public MyDTO findDTO(Long answerId);
```

My interface which I use for the projection:

```
public interface MyDTO {
    String getTextAnswer();
}
```

From my domain object annotated with `@Entity`:

```
private String textAnswer;
```

My testcase which reproduce which reproduce this error. If I comment out the line with `a.getTextAnswer()` it runs ok.

```
@Test
public void findFormPublishedAnswersInterfaceDTOById() {
    FormPublishedAnswersInterfaceDTO a = answerRepository.findFormPublishedAnswersInterfaceDTOById(21540241L);
    assertEquals("test", a.getTextAnswer());
}
```

I have tried different hints I found by the help of google :) like annotating `private String textAnswer` with `@Lob`, `@Type(type = "text")` and `@Column(name = "text", columnDefinition = "CLOB")` without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the exception carefully, you should understand that the JDBC driver reports that the type is a `Clob`, so your DTO must look like this instead:

```
public interface MyDTO {
    Clob getTextAnswer();
}
```